# Can I use remote build for Cordova app without Visual Studio?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-cordova, taco

In the past I have built my Cordova apps with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova and remote build on a provisioned Mac (from macincloud).

I'm now using VS Code rather than Visual Studio, and wondering if there is a way of doing it with command line tools instead?

Answer (score 8):

Turns out you can with TACO CLI:

```
npm install -g taco-cli

taco remote add ios
```

Then it prompts you for the remote details